# How can I ensure that websocket message delivered in Spring in synchronous request?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

Actually I solved this problem by writing "very custom" handling, but I'm not happy about it, and I think that there should be transparent way to do it.

So the story is:

1. "One" user comes and register for some event for listenting with
   websocket
2. "Another" user comes and firing this event. And more over this event    is for particular user "One" and only for him. And we
   making some changes in DB(transaction is open). One important
   thing is that "Another" user can be not exactly "user", but some another backend sending HTTP request, or even inner scheduled task.
3. If somehow message hasn't been delivered and processed we need to    rollback data and return error response for "Another" user.

Of course at first we go and read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Ok, lets start with simple and extend TextWebSocketHandler store websocket session, and send message from "Another" user to "One" using it. The problem is that it has no  verifing that message delivered - session can expire(or even browser may freeze, and etc.) and we have no exception thrown.

Ok, then we read documentation further and meet "STOMP Over WebSocket Messaging Architecture" and it looks like there we can have this verification, but this API looks like it is interaction from websocket to websocket. In my case event should be fired not from websocket request.

There are similar questions:

[Web Socket - Spring : Confirm of message received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490945/web-socket-spring-confirm-of-message-received)

[How to assure reliable message delivery of websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120943/how-to-assure-reliable-message-delivery-of-websockets/29121298#29121298)

But they can be happy with STOMP, or offer async API like Cettia project http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Beta1/

So the question is: is there ready implementation/library/etc. for transparent verification of message delivering with synchronous API?