# How can I capture failed WebSocket messages?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm writing a server that wants to make sure it replies to all responses if possible. If a socket disconnects, when it reconnects with the old session ID, I want the server to re-send the packets that should have gone over the socket.

However, as far as I can tell, there's no way to properly detect asynchronous errors, which is to say errors that occur at the network level. [`WebSocket#send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send) throws an error if we already know that the WebSocket is in an invalid state, but if the client were to disconnect while the message was in the queue, I believe (hope) JavaScript would have already moved on.

There is an `error` event, but I see no way of associating it with the messages that I've tried to send.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(...);
// ... ensure the WebSocket is open at some point
// and we can assume `ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN` at the time of this call
try {
  ws.send(
    message
  );
} catch (e) {
  bufferedMessages.push(message);
}
```

but I don't think this would call `bufferedMessages.push(message)` if the client disconnects while `ws.send(message)` is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, have the client echo back the messages that it got, all the time.

Or have it resend the last message that it got, on reconnect, and keep a sliding window buffer on the server.

Or a combo. Tag each message with a UUID, and have the client ack them by UUID and flush them from the server buffer on ack. That gives you a pretty solid sliding window that matches what you know has been delivered.

The [first Google hit for "WebSockets reliable"](https://medium.com/@yuanoook/reliable-message-communication-within-websocket-40a273df318) has this to say:

> But, WebSocket is unreliable, you don’t know anything if the clients missed some messages because the connection was broken in a while. How about if the messages are critical for your clients.

[The 8 Fallacies of Distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing) #1: "The network is reliable".

Comment: It seems odd to implement an ACK system on top of WebSockets, when WebSockets are supposed to be reliable... I did find a duplicate question actually.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's not a duplicate as it's [for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120943/how-to-assure-reliable-message-delivery-of-websockets). It recommends using [Stomp](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html) which is [implemented in JS as well](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stomp/stompjs)

Comment: Care to link to it?

Comment: (linked in previous comment)

Comment: I see... so WebSockets are reliable insofar as they use TCP underneath, but there's no guarantee that the actual application got the message, which means there's a window where the network layer could have succeeded but the application layer did not. So I need to create application layer ACKs. I suppose I thought WebSockets did this, but I was conflating the guarantees of WebSockets with the guarantees of TCP. Thanks!